# How can I get better names for function parameters

Tags: android, naming

I am new to android programming and I see in tutorials people have better parameters names for example in ExpandableListView in getView function parameters are like groupPosition, parent and so but in my Android Studio they are i, i1 which is really non intuitive.

Comment: You should be posting this question to Android Studio Forum instead. File a bug report and explain your concern.

Answer (score 0):

If you press `Alt+Insert` on Windows or `CMD+n` on OSX you can can generate some methods: getters, setters, constructors.... and `Override methods`. If you you click on it and choose the method you want you will have the right names.

You even have a shortcut on Windows: `Ctrl+O`. On OSX it is `^+O`